# Formatting text based on UserDefaults

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, nsuserdefaults

Lets say i have an settings view in my app where a user can select 'Imperial' or 'Metric'. these settings are stored in userDefaults like so:

```
enum UserDefaultsKeys: String {
    case measurementUnit = "measurementUnit"
}

enum MeasurementUnit: String, CaseIterable {
    case metric = "metric"
    case imperial = "Imperial"
}



class UserDefaultsWrapper: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var measurementUnit: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(measurementUnit, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.measurementUnit.rawValue)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        let locale = Locale.current
        let systemMeasurementUnit = locale.usesMetricSystem ? MeasurementUnit.metric : MeasurementUnit.imperial
        self.measurementUnit = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.measurementUnit.rawValue) ?? systemMeasurementUnit.rawValue
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    @StateObject var userDefaultsWrapper = UserDefaultsWrapper()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            HStack {
                Text("Units \(userDefaultsWrapper.measurementUnit)")
                Picker(selection: $userDefaultsWrapper.measurementUnit, label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(MeasurementUnit.allCases, id: \.self) { unit in
                        Text(unit.rawValue)
                            .tag(unit.rawValue)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        .navigationTitle("Settings")
    }
}
```

Now the app can add workout sessions which i will always store in metric and convert to imperial if needed. If they create a workout in imperial i will first convert it to metric to store it and to show it i will convert it back to imperial values.

to store these workouts i use core data. i want to have a formattedMeasurement computed property in my coreDataProperties file like this:

```
extension WorkoutSession {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<WorkoutSession> {
        return NSFetchRequest<WorkoutSession>(entityName: "WorkoutSession")
    }

    @NSManaged public var created_at: Date?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var updated_at: Date?
    @NSManaged public var measurement: Double

    override public func awakeFromInsert() {
        super.awakeFromInsert()
        setPrimitiveValue(UUID(), forKey: "id")
        setPrimitiveValue(Date(), forKey: "updated_at")
    }
    
    
    var formattedMeasurement: String {
        let userDefaultsWrapper = UserDefaultsWrapper()
        let measurementUnit = MeasurementUnit(rawValue: userDefaultsWrapper.measurementUnit) ?? MeasurementUnit.metric
        return measurementUnit == .metric ? // convert to metric : // convert to imperial
    }
    
}
```

The settings tab and the workout tab are both accessible via a TabView.

Now if i change the measurement settings on the settings page and i go back to the workoutView the `formattedMeasurement` is not updated. only when i restart the app of force update that view by visiting another view outside the tabView.

I think this has something to do with the way classes work because i make 2 instances of the UserDefaulsWrapper class.
What is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Have you looked into `@AppStorage`?

Comment: Yes I did. AppStorage will only trigger view updates if used directly inside a View struct.

Comment: But by placing an @AppStorage on your `WorkoutView`, it would trigger a re-render when the value changed, which would then call the `formattedMeasurement` computed property in your `WorkoutSession`, right? Hard to say, I guess, since you're not actually showing how `WorkoutSession` relates or is used.